# Десятых, сотых, тысячных процента или процентов?

Tags: числительные, управление, число

Десятых, сотых, тысячных процента или процентов?

Answer (score 4):

"Полное" (математическое) словосочетание выглядит так:
**одна десятая часть** (*чего? Р. п.*) **одного процента** (или сотая, или тысячная).

Упрощенное — так: **десятая** (сотая, тысячная) **процента** (множественному числу *процентов* тут "взяться" неоткуда).
В словосочетании склоняется, соответственно, только порядковое числительное:

Составляет две десятых процента; приближается к тридцати трём сотым процента; сто четыре тысячных процента.

**Дополнение-разъяснение**

Возможно, кто-то скажет, что я не предоставила в своем ответе никакого правила.
Оно есть, и звучит так: **существительным управляет дробная часть.**
Это означает, что существительное в словосочетаниях с дробями ставится в Р. п. ед. числа.

1. Это правило касается не только десятичных дробей, указанных в вопросе, но и обыкновенных (или простых) дробей — **m/n**:
   три седьмых **километра**, семь восьмых **гектара**, пять шестых **яблока**.
2. Если существительное имеет форму только множественного числа (чернила, брюки, сутки), то, естественно, употребляется Р. п. мн. числа:
   три десятых суток, две пятых чернил.
3. Мы можем как угодно менять (варьировать) обозначение дробей — падеж и число существительного не изменится:
   5,2 % от 5,2 га = пять и две десятых **процента** от пяти и двух десятых **гектара**;
   0,75 руб = семьдесят пять сотых **рубля** = три четверти **рубля** = три четвертых **рубля**.

Некоторые вопросы-ответы можно посмотреть [**здесь**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B0).

Comment: Нужно ли здесь ПРАВИЛО? Вот и Розенталь говорит: при смешанном числе существительным управляет дробь, а не целое число.  А как ДРОБЬ МОЖЕТ УПРАВЛЯТЬ существительным? При управлении главное слово задает падеж зависимому, поэтому надо определить это главное слово. К примеру, пять десятых  километра. У дроби есть числитель и знаменатель, которые присутствуют в названии дроби, но они не являются главным словом.

Comment: Главное слово здесь пропущено: пять десятых долей/частей километра. Часть (доля) километра - вот сочетание, в котором существительное  "часть"  ВСЕГДА задает Р.п. существительному  "километр".  И больше не надо никаких объяснений, здесь только простая (чистая) ГРАММАТИКА, не требующая НИКАКИХ ПРАВИЛ.

Answer (score 3):

Правильно: **(пять) десятых, сотых, тысячных (долей) процента (управление Р.п.).**

Или: две, три, четыре десятые (доли) процента.

Примеры:

Впрочем, стоимость Аи-95 в целом по стране выросла на те же **три десятых процента**. [Хасан Ганиев. Новости (2002) // «Автопилот», 2002.09.15]

Рост валового продукта составил один и **четыре десятых процента**. [Виктор Левашов. Заговор патриота (2000)]

Ошибка:

Думаю, что вероятная ошибка этой оценки ― **несколько десятых процентов**, что не так уж плохо». [И. С. Шкловский. Новеллы и популярные статьи (1982)]

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое)